# What is the correct way to configure ASGI application for channels in Django?

Tags: python, django, channel, daphne, asgi

I've just started to learn about channels and asgi in django
in few tutorials that i've seen they do this to configure the asgi apllication

asgi.py

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http':get_asgi_application(),
})
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'chat'
]


ASGI_APPLICATION = 'config.asgi.application'
```

to check when i run my server it was supposed to be running on asgi/channel server like this

```
Starting ASGI/Channels version development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

but mine is still running on the default one

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

when i use daphne and put inside installed apps instead of channels

```
    'daphne',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'chat'
]
```

it works fine

```
Starting ASGI/Daphne version 4.0.0 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

can someone tell me what is going on here?and how exactly django works with asgi?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking why tutorials you have read don't say that daphne must be in INSTALLED_APPS, because that's new in version 4. The official tutorial is decent enough to use